# QDom Remove Element

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom, getelementsbytagname

I have used the following codes to parse a XML file. My aim is to detect if the `<Name>` element is "ABC", and I will remove its `<Malfunction>` contents. However, my codes only allow me to read in "Name" and remove all the element tags with `<Name>`.

Is it possible to check if the `<Name>` element tag contains "ABC" and remove the contents within the `<Malfunction></Malfunction>` tags, including the tags themselves?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

.cpp:

```
QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("Name");

while(!nodes.isEmpty())
{
    QDomNode node = nodes.at(0);
    node.parentNode().removeChild(node);
}
```

.xml:

```
<InjectedMalfunctions>
 <Malfunction>
  <Segment>ABC</Segment>
  <Name>ABC failure</Name>
  <Time>00:00:00</Time>
 </Malfunction>
 <Malfunction>
  <Segment>DEF</Segment>
  <Name>DEF failure</Name>
  <Time>00:00:00</Time>
 </Malfunction>
</InjectedMalfunctions>
```

Output .xml:

```
<InjectedMalfunctions>
 <Malfunction>
  <Segment>ABC</Segment>
  <Time>00:00:00</Time>
 </Malfunction>
 <Malfunction>
  <Segment>DEF</Segment>
  <Time>00:00:00</Time>
 </Malfunction>
</InjectedMalfunctions>
```

Wanted .xml:

```
<InjectedMalfunctions>
 <Malfunction>
  <Segment>DEF</Segment>
  <Name>DEF failure</Name>
  <Time>00:00:00</Time>
 </Malfunction>
</InjectedMalfunctions>
```

---

The following code removes all the `<Malfunction>` tags, instead of just the first `<Malfunction>` group.

Edited .cpp:

```
QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("Name");

while(!nodes.isEmpty())
{
    QDomNode node = nodes.at(0);
    node.nodeValue().contains("ABC");
    QDomNode toRemove = node.parentNode();
    toRemove.parentNode().removeChild(toRemove);
}
```

Comment: Is there anybody who can advise on this? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this will work.
Check for ABC:

```
node.nodeValue().contains("ABC");
```

remove complete

```
QDomnode toRemove = node.parentNode();
toRemove.parentNode().removeChild(toRemove);
```

Comment: I tried your mentioned codes, but it removed all the `<Malfunction>` tags. Am I doing anything wrong here? Please see my edited version above.